# ng-touched not resetting on .markAsUntouched for a Custom Control

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a simple custom control in an an Angular 2 form that when it you edit  the field then reset it via the **.markAsUntouched**, it doesn't remove the **ng-touched** class.

The sample form looks like this:

```
<form #editForm="ngForm">
    <input [(ngModel)]="title" name="title2" type="text"/>
    <app-textbox label="Template Driven Model" [showLabel]="true" 
     [(ngModel)]="title" name="title"> </app-textbox>
     <button (click)="resetTempalteDriven()">Reset Template Driven</button>
 </form>
```

In this example the standalone input control resets correctly. The app-textbox component's html looks like this:

```
<div>
<div class="fg-line">
    <label *ngIf="label && showLabel" [ngClass]="{ 'font-bold': required }">{{label}}</label>
    <input type="text"   style="cursor: text" 
        [(ngModel)]="value" [required]="required" [disabled]="disabled" [placeholder]="placeholder" [id]="identifier" />
</div>
```

And the reset for the form looks like this:

```
  resetTempalteDriven(){ 

      this.editForm.form.markAsPristine();
      this.editForm.form.markAsUntouched();

      this.editForm.controls["title"].markAsUntouched();
   }
```

I have put the entire app here https://github.com/jmarbutt/ng2-angular-issue

The form looks like this after touching both input fields then hitting reset.
[image]

They both should be white at this point.

So my question is why does the ng-touched not remove correctly on the **markAsUntouched**?

Comment: First of all you do not change `touched` state for your `app-textbox` control. You should call `touch()` method for this. For example in `textbox.component.html` add `<input style="cursor: text"
            [(ngModel)]="value" [required]="required" (blur)="touch()"`

Comment: After that class `ng-touched/ng-untouched` will be changed for `app-textbox` element but not for your inner `input[ngModel=value"` element because it has no relation with your form

Comment: I have done this with reactive forms that connects the form control from top to bottom but with template driven and this pattern it makes it almost impossible to do. The problem in our app we have the need for both a templates approach like this and reactive forms. I haven’t been able to find a way to make this work

Comment: I am going create plunker for you. I see you can do many improvement of your code

Comment: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` Do't import all rxjs code. Use `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` instead

Comment: You can omit constructor in your derived class if base class has the same parameters

Comment: `type="text"` is redundant. Its default type

Comment: `this.editForm.controls["title"].markAsUntouched()` is redundant. `form.markAsUntouched` will go through all child controls

Comment: Yes that code is redundant just was proving a point and yes there is a lot of cleanup but this actually came from a larger class and just did it to simplify the issue

Comment: @yurzui yes some of this was done really quickly and not perfect because of the plugin I have that did the auto includes but was just trying to provide a simple example

Comment: I see. Check my example https://plnkr.co/edit/x90RlZu5J502TMFriU55?p=preview especially `FieldControlBase.ngOnInit` method

Comment: Another solution is use specific css rule for inner input https://plnkr.co/edit/0BXsnAm62Hc9ptdgTZ1b?p=preview See `style.css` but `(blur)="touch()"` is necessary in both cases

Comment: @yurzui your first plunker did the trick. Thanks

Comment: The second one was good but I feel like the first one was more complete.

Comment: @yurzui So now where I am with this is I want this still work on reactive forms, I have updated my git repo to try to make this work. It is like I can only make it with either/or not both.

Answer (score 0):

Making the button type to button solved my issue